# I do not understand joining tables

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I'm using Cake version 2.5.4
I have two tables.

A call arbols which consists of the following fields:
id (int 11)
nombre (varchar (255)
especie:id (int 11)

The second table called fotos consists of the following fields:

```
id (int 11)
foto (varchar 255)
foto_dir (varchar 255)
arbol_id (int 11)
```

Although the Arbol model is related to the Especie model,
I leave it aside to the latter because it is not a reason for consultation.
The Arbol Model has a hasMany relationship with the Foto model.

In the Arbol model I have the following:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Foto'=> array(
        'className' => 'Foto',
        'foreignKey' => 'arbol_id',
        'dependent' => true
        )
    );

In the Foto model I have the following:
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Arbol'=> array(
            'className'=>'Arbol',
            'foreign_key'=>'arbol_id'
            )
        );
```

Now, inside ArbolsController in public function view ($ id = null)
I want to do the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM arboles as a join fotos as f on a.id=f.arbol_id
```

So I return all the photos related to an id of a particular tree passed as parameter in view
If this query is done using MySQL

```
$registros=mysqli_query($conexion," select * from arboles as a join fotos as f on a.id=f.arbol_id")
```

it works.
But if I want to do it using the query method in such ways:

```
$registros = $this->Arbol->query("select * from arboles as a INNER JOIN fotos as f ON a.id=f.arbol_id");
$registros = $this->Arbol->query("select * from arboles as a INNER JOIN fotos as f ON a.id=f.arbol_id");
```

It does not work
Reading the Cookbook I see there is a way to make joins.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

I dont understand her

I would appreciate it if you can explain it to me.

From already thank you very much!

Comment: Check this [LINK about containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#using-containable) maybe can help you

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the `query` method directly if you can avoid it.
What you can do is using a standard find, joining your tables with [containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#using-containable) (or [linkable](https://github.com/lorenzo/linkable)).

Something like this should work:

```
$registros = $this->Arbol->find('all', array(
    'contain' => 'Foto'
));
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Comment: I just can not use the query method.
I use mysql directly, which is worse.
Replacing such call with your answer, I get:
Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 5484247 bytes)
File: /var/www/html/cakephp-2.5.4/lib/Cake/Utility/String.php .

I still do not understand how to make a join. Please be more specific. I'm just starting to learn CakePHP.

Comment: Let's start with a plain find. If you try with `$registros = $this->Arbol->find('all'); debug($registros);` what do you obtain?

Answer (score 0):

There is another way by you can join the tables in cakephp i.e customized joins

> Create an array of tables whom you want to join, such as

```
$joins = array(
        array(
            'table' => 'fotos',//Table name
            'alias' => 'Foto', //Model name
            'type' => 'INNER', // type of join
            'conditions' => array(
                'Arbol.id = Foto.arbol_id'
            ) //Condition for join
        )
    );

$this->Arbol->find('all', array(
 'joins' => $joins,
 'conditions'=> array(Arbol.id => $id),
 'fields' => array()
))
```

This will return all the photos information related to an id